# How to use rufus to create bootable usb(Sony 16GB) for WIndows 10 iso file(Win10_1909_English_x64.iso of 5.04GB size)?

Tags: windows-10, iso-image, bootable-media, rufus

1. Downloaded file `Win10_1909_English_x64.iso`
2. Size of downloaded file - 5.04GB
3. USB - Sony 16GB USB 2.0 (14.4GB available space)
4. Downloaded Rufus 3.8.1580
5. Using `diskpart` and typing `list disk` shows there is an asterisk mark under GPT for Disk 0
6. System Information BIOS mode - UEFI
7. Current OS - Windows 10 Home single language
8. Cannot download more than 2GB per day in my internet connection, so I cannot use media creation tool and have downloaded the iso file
9. Do not want to use reset as it keeps the bloatware. My main aim is to clean install Windows 10 on my laptop.

When I insert the USB and open Rufus it shows many options; what should I choose for: 
 (or is there another method or tool for making bootable USB?)

- Partition Scheme
- Target System
- File System
- Cluster size

After installing Windows 10, will it automatically activate if the laptop came preinstalled with it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of : [How to do UEFI+GPT with a iso file greater than 4GB](https://superuser.com/a/1289251/269373).  Try *Boot Selection :* `UEFI:NTFS`, *Partition scheme :* `gpt`, *Target system :* `UEFI (non CSM)`, *File system :* `NTFS`, *Cluster size :* `4096`  .  It should be automatically activated

Comment: To elaborate on @lx07's comment, Rufus will automatically select all the correct parameters once you select the Windows install ISO.  The only thing you may manually have to do is turn off exclusive access _only if Rufus throws an error during the process_: **`ALT`+`,`**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I get a clean ISO of a specific build of Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1108085/where-can-i-get-a-clean-iso-of-a-specific-build-of-windows-10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partition Scheme and Target system - GPT Partitioning scheme for UEFI

File System - NTFS

Cluster size - Keep what is there default

> OR is there another method or tool for making bootable usb.

There are tools but Rufus is fine. 
From [rufus](https://rufus.ie)

> Oh, and Rufus is fast. For instance it's about twice as fast as Unetbootin, Universal USB Installer or Windows 7 USB download tool

......

> And after installing Windows 10 Home single language ,will it get automatically activated if laptop came preinstalled with Windows 10 Home single language.

An example
For Dell taken from [FAQ regarding product key](https://www.dell.com/support/article/in/en/inbsd1/sln290004/windows-product-key-frequently-asked-questions-faq?lang=en)

> For Windows 8 and Windows 10, the Product Key is "injected" onto the
>   computer motherboard at the factory. Installation and activation of
>   Windows refer to the information in the BIOS of the computer to verify
>   authenticity. Owners of these computers do not need a physical key to
>   input.

Comment: You need NTFS for file size > 4GB.

Comment: @lx07 NTFS always needs to be used with UEFI installs when Rufus is used... that being said, the 4GB file size limit applies to a single file, and the largest file within a Windows install ISO is the `install.esd` (~3.7GB).  The limit would apply if copying the ISO itself directly to the filesystem, but not extracting files from the install ISO to the filesystem _(unless one of the extracted files were >4GB)_

Answer (score 1):

You can perform a full reset from within Windows itself.
Settings > Update & Security > Recovery

[image]

Alternatively you can download the [Media Creation Tool directly from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10), which will correctly make your boot USB.

You Windows Activation is stored at Microsoft & will be automatically re-applied if you reinstall to the same hardware.

Comment: Can please provide just the configuration of Rufus to create bootable usb for uefi?

Comment: I've no clue how to do that - it is not necessary to know, just do it from Windows. I've given you two working methods, as asked in your question "...OR is there another method or tool for making bootable usb" Yes there is, see above.